# how to delete last line gtk.Textbuffer

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, gtk, pygtk

I have a list filled up with text buffer like;

```
self.textbuffer.insert(self.textbuffer.get_end_iter(), '\n' + str(values))
```

I need to delete the last line of the list with a button press and I use ;

```
self.textbuffer.delete(self.textbuffer.get_iter_at_line(self.textbuffer.get_line_count()-1),self.textbuffer.get_end_iter())
```

With this code, delete operation fires up only once and the others doesnt also there is no fault code ....

How can I delete the last line of textbuffer?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't removing the newline that seperates the last line from the prior line. So you need to call backwards char on the result of get_iter_at_line to get an iter on the prior line just before the newline.

```
start = self.textbuffer.get_iter_at_line(self.textbuffer.get_line_count()-1)
start.backward_char()
self.textbuffer.delete(start, self.textbuffer.get_end_iter())
```

Comment: ps. `backward_char(2)` can be used to go backwards 2 characters